# Facebook rss feed url change

Tags: facebook, rss, feed

I am accessing the Facebook rss feed url https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=XXXX for our company updates, but url some times work and sometimes not. 
Can I use same url or different url? In near future , is there any functionality change happening to the above url. Please help me in this regard

Thanks
Madhu

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's support for RSS feeds is somewhat iffy.  You're much better off using the Graph API, which is fully supported, and has a lot more flexibility and parameters.  Here's the information on getting posts from a page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed